# Application cannot access USB Token in remote

Tags: c#, digital-signature, remote-access, windows-server-2012, signer

I'm trying to create a C# console application using [SignFile lib](https://www.signfiles.com/) to access Token USB (contain Digital Signature) to sign a folder of PDF files.

The problem is after build Release to run on Windows Server 2012, this application run successful without any error (with Administrator account). But when I try to run with remote in my laptop (using Administrator account too), this application run error with this code:

> Unhandled Exception : System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Bypassing PIN exception: An internal error occured

Anyone got any ideas about this situation?

Comment: Configuration you run program is very unclear from your description. But before asking question please make sure device and library support such configuration (access to remote USB devices is often limited/tricky)

Comment: Remote signing needs to be achieved using Browser Extension if it is web application https://stackoverflow.com/a/55676351/9659885 or for Client Server application, server needs to get content signed from client through some communication channel.

Comment: When application was installed was it installed for all users?  Was a certificate created load for each user? You may need to add the certificate to your user account.