# Get Client cert information in javascript/angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, browser, certificate

is there any way to get informations about the installed client certificates using javascript or better, angular?

Informations like name of cert, username in our case.
Or can we check if a cert is installed?

Thanks
Bitbaggi

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question isn't really specific enough to be answered - but don't be put off if it gets closed. With all questions concerning "can JavaScript do this within a browser?", it is best to ask yourself "would I be happy if some website I visited could do this?" If the answer is "I'd be pretty scared if they could access this", the answer is usually that it can't.

Comment: No, it is not possible due to security restrictions of browsers. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50208561/6371459

Comment: You may use any of the available Browser Extension to achieve this. Signer Digital Chrome Extension is one such free provided by my company.  The part of answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55757349/9659885 may help.