# Apply Digital Signatures in asp.net form fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, digital-signature

I have a requirement where-in I have a web form with various asp.net form fields. The values entered by the user in this fields have to be signed. The signing key would be in a USB attached to the computer.

These form fields entered (say textboxes etc), eventually become a document, which will be digitally signed and encrypted, and will be sent back to the server.

Currently the app is made using Java applet, but it is having its issue. Do we have any similar approaches in .Net framework using c#, where we can create this utility,which should be accessible from all browsers, be downloaded from the web and have one click deploy features.

Any approach or method to create a utility which can be invoked from any browser the response back to browser or directly to the server.

Thanks In Advance!!!...

Comment: as far as I know - this is a browser (JavaScript) responsability to sign a document with key from USB dongle, if so - there should be no issue with switching from Java applet to C# web application. What is an actual problem you're facing?

Comment: Any changes in the browser or Java settings might disables the functionality. Also
cant troubleshoot the failures, need to reinstall from scratch, so it becomes a time consuming approach. Also there is Version Compatibility issues & Security issues

Comment: It is not possible to sign/encrypt data from the browser due to security restrictions to access to system keystore. See alternatives here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50208561/6371459

Comment: You may need to use Browser Extension. One such extension is provided free by my company. Please refer to parts of the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55757349/9659885

Comment: @Siddharth, was just wondering whether above link solved your issue... I have updated answer at above link. You may also refer to this answer which points to complete downloadable C# project. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55676351/9659885