# Digitally sign PDF by epass 2003 DSC usb token in website on ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, certificate, digital-signature, digital-certificate

I want to digitally sign PDF by epass2003 DSC USB token on my website on ASP.NET C#.

My requirement step by step on website

1. Firstly client attach the *usb don-gal* on his machine then code verify it
2. Then sign the PDF with *DSC* USB token *Certificate* with sign-in

Suggest me right full examples. I have write lot's of code with #x509certificate2 and #pkcs11 which is not working for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sign PDF with plain JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216843/sign-pdf-with-plain-javascript)