# How to include digital signature in asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, digital-signature

I have a digital signature token with password. I have created a textbox in my web form to enter the password of digital certificate. But I am new to this. I read lot of documents but could not find a proper answer.
How to use the USB digital token to digitally sign and verify the web form by inserting its password?

Comment: you can use hellosign or docusign api.

hellosign : https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/sign-contracts-with-asp-net-mvc-and-hellosign-api

Comment: hellosign and docusign api are having high prices. Is there any free api that we can try ?

Answer (score 0):

USB Token password will be asked by USB Token driver / middle-ware, you don't need password textbox on the web form.

To digitally sign from modern browsers, you may need to use Browser Extension, which accesses client's local Certificate Store through Host application installed as a part of Browser Extension on client's device. The USB Token may be used to Authenticate user using Digital Signature, Sign Content such as eReturn or XML, Sign PDF document on the server, etc.

Please refer to this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55676351/9659885) for working asp.net project and Javascript code.