# Capture a physical signature from a USB device into a web page

Tags: asp.net, usb, signature

We've written a MVC web application for a client that they're typically interacting with from Windows 10 PCs. They've now asked us for a solution whereby the users can attach a USB device that captures physical signatures, and have that captured signature uploaded via a web page in the app.

While this sounds like a general permissions/privacy no no, I'm hopeful maybe some sort of solution exists out there...?

Thanks
James

Comment: A website will never have direct access to the device. So the user needs to upload that signature or has to install a piece of software that handles the communication between their computer and your server.

Comment: Please refer to this SO Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55676351/9659885  This also contains link to downlodable MVC project. If you want to sign content, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/55692742/9659885

Comment: Did the above answers helped ? Please let me know...

Answer (score 0):

there is a WebUSB API for chrome you could used. it's javascript api, you could communicate using ajax for the backend.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/access-usb-devices-on-the-web