# How to create document signature application with some input from receipt

Tags: jquery, ionic-framework, digital-signature, document

I want to create an application where the user will upload documents it can be PDF, Word, Image, and will edit that document and add some input box to take from the user [Signature, CompanyName, Checkbox]

And then save that document and another user will do the digital signature.

is there some plugin there which resolve and speed up my work.

Example like DocuSign application doing.

Comment: If you are looking to sign PDF using Digital Signature Certificates issued by Certifying Authority in USB Token, please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55676351/9659885

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sign PDF with plain JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216843/sign-pdf-with-plain-javascript)