# How to sign a pdf with USB token certificate from angular/javascript

Tags: pdf, certificate, usb, token, signature

I got the Certificate as hex data from the USB Token. i have to sign a pdf using this certificate. How to sign a pdf using token certificate from front end(angular/javascript)?

I am using [this reference](https://gk.palem.in/digital-signature.html) for getting certificate from token in browser.

Comment: Refer to this SO Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55676351/9659885