# Add Multiple Digital SIgnatures in a PDF using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, npm, digital-signature

I am trying to implement **Multiple Digital Signatures** on one PDF Whereby i can track the persons who have digitally signed that PDF. Is there any npm packages I can use with nodeJS .

Comment: Is this a web application? What is source of signature? PFX or USB Tokens ? In India Individual Signatures are issued only in USB Tokens...

Comment: Its a nodeJs WebApp . Trying to create key cryptographically (AES, RSA, SHA256) and embed the digital signature to a PDF (the data inside the PDF is constant).

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55676351/9659885 wherein you would be able to use Signer.Digital Browser Extension on browser side. On server side you can use any PDF component or Library as you wish.