# Digital signature on PDF clientside / serverside

Tags: pdf, web-applications, digital-signature, server-side, client-side

I have a project and I need help... The idea is a web application that allows users to sign a pdf located on server via a **jar** file (which is also on server) that take a pdf and **PKCS#12** file (.p12 or .pfx) and generate a digitally signed **PDF**.

1. How is it possible to make the signing process take place on **clientside** using the .jar file ??
2. Or how can I recieve the user's PKCS#12 file and use it on server to allow user to sign the pdf without saving it on server (**serverside**)??

any helpful Ideas or recommandations!

Comment: @KJ  *"generally you can only sign on behalf of somebody else, if you are a valid certified notoriety"* - beware, that depends on your respective legislation. There are legislations in which it suffices if there is a contract between you and that somebody else.

Comment: Refer to answer [sign-pdf-with-plain-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55676351/9659885) for client side signing. Server just needs to send hash of the document to client browser.