# Sign generated PDF from user smartCard or token Angular / NodeJS

Tags: angular, pkcs#11, chilkat

I have an angular front End and NodeJS back end App.
I can generate some PDFs.

Before to be able to save the PDF, i would love to have a pop up window asking the user to sign it with its own electronic signature, which each of my users have on their own smart card or USB device.

I have no idea how to connect my app with the users' smart card in order to get some callback when the document is signed in the browser

I found  PKCS#11 or Node JS chilkat as some libraries in this direction, but nothing really helps so far

Any ideas how to connect my front end or back end to users smart card or token with digital signature and get a callback of the user has signed the document so i can save it with the signature on the server?

Regards

Comment: Hi K J. This is what i want to avoid. The user should juust be asked to sign the generated document and enter the password from his token or smart card. The app should do the rest. I do not want to involve the user to download, sign manually and resend the document

Comment: Ive seen something like i want to achieve in my online banking. 
The file is being generated and a pop up asks me if i want to sign it. I do not see the generated file yet and if i confirm in the pop up, I enter my crededntials from the smart card and the file is being generated directly with the signature on it. This is what i want to achieve, no idea how to do it:)

Comment: Please refer to answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55676351/9659885