# I am working on an front end application with react and want to integrate a document signing solution

Tags: adobe, docusignapi, digital-signature, document

I want to integrate Adobe document sign and want to know the gotchas involved. Also I wanted to understand what is the right use case of Adobe and what for Docusign, which to use when.

Thanks and Regards,

I haven't tried implementing it yet, I have just started doing the ground work for it.

Comment: Refer to answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55676351/9659885  which provides documentation of Signer.Digital browser extension JavaScript API.  Working sample is available at https://web.signer.digital

Answer (score 0):

How about you just try something and see what you think?
The [DocuSign Quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) allows you to pick from Bash, C#, Java, Node.js, PHP, PowerShell, Python, Ruby and give you working code in seconds.

The code will include your own account configuration with OAuth 2.0 all set up to make API calls, so you don't need to do any authentication work, you can just see how it works and decide then how you want to proceed.

Comment: Sure thanks Inbar,I have actually done an integration with Docusign sometime back but it turned out to be very complicated. This was a couple of years ago. Do you think things have changed since then ? Also I wanted to know if there is anyone who knows about both and can tell me if one or the other is right for my use case of letting users view and sign agreements online.

Comment: what do you mean by "complicated" ? was it just a learning curve? was there something you were not able to accomplish? was it a complex scenario ?