# How can Java application running in docker, read from the smart card reader?

Tags: java, docker, smartcard

I have a Java application running via Docker. This application has an endpoint which I can hit from other services to sign PDF documents. To sign these documents, Java app must read data from a smart card.

I don't know where to plug this smart card reader (it has USB cable) so that my docker container can read data from it. Also, there will be only one smart card which will have to do all the work and multiple services/clients will access this java service. So it's not possible to ask every user to plug the card reader into their computer and try to read the info on the client side and send it to the server.

Is there any way to do this? Or is Docker not going to work and I should try IIS?

I can run it locally, meaning when I ran this java application from my local environment, with the card reader plugged into the same machine, it worked fine.

Comment: In general, it's tricky to access host hardware devices from inside a container, and this might be better done with a host-native JVM.  On native Linux, USB devices don't necessarily have fixed paths, so it's hard to connect them to a container; if you're using Docker Desktop on any OS, there's a hidden Linux VM which will make host hardware completely inaccessible.

Comment: What if I don't use Docker. What are the ways to accomplish this?

Comment: Use Browser Extension, refer to answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55676351/9659885

Answer (score -1):

you can add your smart card as vloume in your server and in your docker host
after that you can share this smart card to every one in your network via nfs share or even every one in public network
the result is every user can access this volume via nfs share

Comment: Full-blown smart cards with the ability to sign something are unlikely to be addressable as a mapped drive, as opposed to a SD (storage) card.