# How to sign pdf document with certificate on PKCS11 USB token protected with the PIN?

Tags: python, pdf, certificate, digital-signature, pkcs#11

I want to write a python script that lists to the user all the certificates that are on the PKCS11 USB token. When the user selects the desired certificate, the script needs to sign the input pdf document using that certificate. So far I have been able to get the list of certificates that are on the USB token, but I don't know how to now (using a pin) extract the private key of the selected certificate and sign the pdf document. Here is the code I currently have:

```
from PyKCS11 import *
from PyKCS11.LowLevel import *
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_der_private_key
from asn1crypto import x509

pkcs11 = PyKCS11Lib()
pkcs11.load('c:\\windows\\system32\\eTPKCS11.dll')

slot = pkcs11.getSlotList(tokenPresent=False)
session = pkcs11.openSession(slot[0], CKF_SERIAL_SESSION | CKF_RW_SESSION)


certs = session.findObjects([(CKA_CLASS, CKO_CERTIFICATE)])
certificates = []

for cert in certs:
    cka_value, cka_id = session.getAttributeValue(cert, [CKA_VALUE, CKA_ID])
    cert_der = bytes(cka_value)
    certificate = x509.Certificate.load(cert_der)
    certificates.append(certificate)

print("Available certificates:")
for i, certificate in enumerate(certificates):
    print(f"{i + 1}. {certificate.subject.human_friendly}")

selected_certificate_index = int(input("Please enter the number of certificate you want to use for signing: ")) - 1
selected_certificate = certificates[selected_certificate_index]

# what now???
```

Now I should somehow extract the private key of the selected certificate (thereby somehow using the pin with which the private key is protected) and sign the given pdf document, but I don't know how to do it. Please, help me with that.

Comment: Is this a desktop application or web application? In case your's is web application and USB is connected to client browser, please refer answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55676351/9659885

Comment: It's a desktop application, so the USB token is connected to the machine where the application is running.

Answer (score 0):

1. You must keep values of `CKA_ID` atrributes `cka_id` for all certificates you are enumerated.
2. You should logon into the token using your PIN.
3. Start search of primate key objects using the corresponding `CKA_ID` value.
4. The result of search must return the only one object that corresponds to certificate selected by the user.

```
certs = session.findObjects([(CKA_CLASS, CKO_CERTIFICATE)])
certificates = []
identifiers = []

for cert in certs:
    cka_value, cka_id = session.getAttributeValue(cert, [CKA_VALUE, CKA_ID])
    cert_der = bytes(cka_value)
    certificate = x509.Certificate.load(cert_der)
    certificates.append(certificate)
    identifiers.append(cka_id)

print("Available certificates:")
for i, certificate in enumerate(certificates):
    print(f"{i + 1}. {certificate.subject.human_friendly}")

selected_certificate_index = int(input("Please enter the number of certificate you want to use for signing: ")) - 1
selected_certificate = certificates[selected_certificate_index]
selected_id = identifiers[selected_certificate_index]

session.Login(CKU_USER, "PIN");
keys = session.findObjects([(CKA_CLASS, CKO_PRIVATE_KEY)])

for key in keys:
    cka_id = session.getAttributeValue(key, [CKA_ID]) 
    if cka_id == selected_id
      # Save the key an leave the loop

# here you can use the key
```

Sorry Python is not my language, so in the example above may be some misprints and lexical errors....

Comment: I tried your code and it does indeed extract the *metadata* about the private key from the USB token (but not the private key itself -- as far as I understand it, it can't be extracted at all because that's how USB tokens generally work. Obviously there's some other way which USB token can be "forced" to do that signing, but I can't find any example code that does it).

So now my main question (to which I am looking for an answer) is: how to use the private key data in the variable key from your code above, to create a digital signature of an existing PDF document?

Comment: Try to adopt some techniques from [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/). There are exits “Generators/Processors for S/MIME and CMS (PKCS7/RFC 3852)”.

Comment: My experience with PKCS#11 is limited to manipulation with low-level objects. PKCS#12 snd CMS is out of my scope.