# How to sign in PAdES with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, digital-signature, smartcard, pkcs#11

I'm trying to create a function in nodejs for digital signature from smart card for signing pdf documents in pades format. I used the pkcs11js library to retrieve the certificate and private key. I used the function to create the signature:

```
pkcs11.C_FindObjectsInit(session, [
     { type: pkcs11js.CKA_CLASS, value: pkcs11js.CKO_CERTIFICATE }
 ]);
 var hObject = pkcs11.C_FindObjects(session);

 var i = 0;
 while (hObject) {
     var attrs = pkcs11.C_GetAttributeValue(session, hObject, [
         { type: pkcs11js.CKA_VALUE }
     ]);
     certificates[i] = attrs[0].value;
     //console.log(attrs[0].value.toString()); prints the certificate data
     hObject = pkcs11.C_FindObjects(session);
     i++;
 }
 pkcs11.C_FindObjectsFinal(session);
 var keys = { privateKey: null, publicKey: null };
 pkcs11.C_FindObjectsInit(session, [
     { type: pkcs11js.CKA_CLASS, value: pkcs11js.CKO_PRIVATE_KEY },
 ]);
 var hObject = pkcs11.C_FindObjects(session);
 while (hObject) {
     var attrs = pkcs11.C_GetAttributeValue(session, hObject, [
         { type: pkcs11js.CKA_CLASS },
         { type: pkcs11js.CKA_TOKEN },
         { type: pkcs11js.CKA_LABEL }
     ]);
     keys.privateKey = hObject;
     hObject = pkcs11.C_FindObjects(session);
 }
 pkcs11.C_FindObjectsFinal(session);

 pkcs11.C_SignInit(session, { mechanism: pkcs11js.CKM_SHA256_RSA_PKCS }, keys.privateKey);
 var signature = pkcs11.C_Sign(session, pdf, Buffer.alloc(2048));
```

How can I sign the PDF now in pades format?

I thought about using node-signpdf library but it requires pkcs#12 format, I don't know, could I convert the certificate (Ber-encoding) to pkcs#12? would this be the right way? what do you recommend?

Comment: Was I unable to explain the needs well or is there no one who can give me some advice?

Comment: Hi @Carmine, (node-)signpdf currenlty only has signpdf/signer-p12 indeed. This was already raised a coulple of times in the repo discussions ( https://github.com/vbuch/node-signpdf/issues?q=label%3Apkcs11 ) but nobody so far has contributed to the package anything related. PRs/ideas/specs are always welcome.

Comment: you may also want to see this fork: https://github.com/SIU-Toba/node-signpdf/blob/feature/pkcs11-token/src/signpdf.js#L121C9-L121C9

Comment: Valery!! I'll take a look at the code... Thanks

Comment: Refer to post https://stackoverflow.com/a/55676351/9659885