# Is necesary HSM and how create it?

Tags: digital-signature, hardware-security-module

in my work i need sign a application for windows and many websites explain that is necessary for this use an HSM.

I tried search information about this but all information that i have found talks about using HSM as API´s.
My questions are the nexts.

1. Is necesary used HSM for this reason?
2. Is possible create a HSM in a usbdrive or a other basic method?
   I understand that if the answer of the second question is no i will need pay for example AWS CloudHSM, Cloud HSM...

Comment: You may use USB SmartCard or USB Token to digitally sign from (web) application if you don't need to sign few thousand documents per hour.. refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55676351/9659885