# How to handle client card/pfx authentication certificate popup in Playwright

Tags: typescript, authentication, alert, playwright, smartcard

My app uses card certificate authentication.
As for now seems like there is no official solution made/suggested by Playwright- according to [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/1799). 
I couldn't found any way to workaround it.

Here's a list of things I've tried:

1. looking for Playwright's offered solution - **not exist** yet.
2. Handle it like a regular alert - **not working**
3. Provide credentials using `browser` or `context`- **not working**
4. Provide credentials using `launchPersistentContext` (chromium only)-
   **not working**
5. Check if it's inside an iFrame - it's not, **looks like this pop-up is
   on a lower level than the DOM**
6. Auth using `context.route("**/*")` and providing pfx using
   `agentOptions` field(workaround somebody suggested in the GitHub
   Issue) -**couldn't figure what I did wrong**
7. send keyboard keys using playwright- no help, looks like **the pop-up
   is on a lower level than Playwright regular session** can reach- which
   led me to the next try:
8. Use Playwright's `CDPSession` in order to use the it's event handler-
   but after I look into [CDP Docs](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/#event-authRequired) seems like they expose the basic `http auth` event, couldn't find anything about `SSL certificate` event.

What I haven't tried yet:

1. Use an external pixel recognition tool- too much time to learn each
   tool, really heavy, and from what I saw most of them require `Java` or
   `Python`

Comment: If this is web application, refer to SO Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55676351/9659885

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround that does the job for now, but I'm not fully satisfied with:

perform windows-level keyboard actions using `node-key-sender` *npm* library:

**Requirements:**
`Java` (`jre` to be precise) must be installed and added to user/system environment variables

**Installation**

```
npm i node-key-sender
```

**Usage**

```
// Warning! Do not touch the keyboard while this code run!
const ks = require("node-key-sender");

await page.goto("<my_url>");
await ks.sendKey("enter");
```

This example navigates to the app and than “pressing” <kbd>enter</kbd> in order to accept the certificate. if there is more than one cert another keys like <kbd>down</kbd> or <kbd>tab</kbd> can be added in order to select another certs.

**The problems** with this solution are the fact that this relay on keyboard timing which is unreliable, prevent parallel execution, require `Java`, and you can’t be sure you’ve selected the correct cert, since you're unable to pick a certificate by it's name.

Answer (score 0):

A great workaround **for *Windows & Chromium* users** - using *Windows Registry* `AutoSelectCertificateForUrls` Chromium Policy

I’m demonstrating on *Chromium/Chrome*, but it’s the same for every other *Chromium-based* browser. (you just need to figure the exact key path)

For the **Playwright Chromium** browser you need to create this registry key:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\Policies\\Chromium\\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls`

> **Note:** According to [google-docs](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9131254?hl=en#zippy=%2Cconfigure-settings-on-windows-computers) If you use the PC Chrome (i.e.
> `channel: "chrome"`)
> you should use this path instead:
> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\Policies\\Google\\Chrome\\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls`

with this value pattern:

```
"1"="{\"pattern\":\"<https://www.example.com\>",\"filter\":{\"ISSUER\":{\"CN\":\"certificate issuer name\", \"L\": \"certificate issuer location\", \"O\": \"certificate issuer org\", \"OU\": \"certificate issuer org unit\"}, \"SUBJECT\":{\"CN\":\"certificate subject name\", \"L\": \"certificate subject location\", \"O\": \"certificate subject org\", \"OU\": \"certificate subject org unit\"}}}"
```

## Code Example

In this example I'm executing the CMD `reg add` command using node-js [exec function](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html):

```
const key = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\Policies\\Chromium\\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls";
const value = "1";
const data = `{\\"pattern\\":\\"${url}\\",\\"filter\\":{\\"SUBJECT\\":{\\"CN\\":\\"${certName}\\"}}}`;

exec(`reg add "${key}" /v "${value}" /d "${data}"`);
```

Now, navigate to your site and the certificate pop-up shouldn't pop-up.